# Клонирование полей ввода

Tags: jquery

Проблема такая. Нужно через форму добавлять несколько однотипных данных (кол-во заранее не известно). Данные имеют несколько свойств. Например, "расходы": вид, наименование, сумма.
Сделал форму с таблицей с полями ввода (input, select). Имена полей задал так

```
<input type="text" name="charges[new][sum]">
<input type="text" name="charges[new][description]>
```

Данные обрабатывает php (как массив).
Захотелось мне несколько расходов за раз отправить. Взял строку с полем ввода, да и клонировал средствами jquery.
Можно ли как-то **легко** сменить индекс у полей ввода ("new" поменять на "new2" или "new3", например) ?

Comment: ничего не мешает после клонирования пройтись и поменять нужный атрибут

Comment: Да это-то понятно. Это же кроме выборки самих полей нужно еще и в значении атрибута часть текста менять. Может что попроще есть?

Comment: Можешь перед отправкой на сервер со всех input c одинаковым name собирать массив и отправлять как одно поле, в такой реализации на сервере не нужно думать сколько возможно будет полей new1,2,n
просто перебираешь массив заранее известного поля

Comment: @sivik_xes, от этого решения я отказался. Проблемы с checkbox, не охота jquery ещё и тут чтобы был

Comment: Ну такой еще вариант, возможно не очень, но 
создать  input type hidden c  name - charges[new][sum]  и со всех текстовых инпутов собирать val этого инпута, получиться что отправка будет без  jquery, но на сервер как тебе и нужно придет массив